# Reload a JComponent

Tags: java, swing, awt

How can I reload a component in a JFrame from inside its own class as if I were to remove it, create a new one and add it back again?

Much like a `this.repaint()`, but actually reconstructing it, if it's possible.

Comment: Why? Instead of creating a new component, just reset the properties of the existing component.

Comment: Because in the constructor I read a file and update the component's contents accordingly, if it was possible it would result in a much cleaner result than replicating the code to read the file and modifying the scope of certain arrays :)

Comment: `than replicating the code` - why do you need to replicate the code? You can create a method. The method will take data from a file and update a component.

Comment: Sure but still I'd need to do many operations instead of just one, I only asked if that was possible

Answer (score 0):

First of all , you should not add a JComponent directly on a frame , Would be better if you add JPanel on JFrame and then add the components on them ..

For Replacing Component on JPanel , you may use the following functions.

```
jPanel.remove(comp);
or
jPanel.removeAll();

jPanel.add(comp);
jPanel.revalidate();
jpanel.repaint();
```

In case you want to do with the JFrame only you need to resize the frame a bit after replacing a component for refreshing the frame using jf.setSize(x,y).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
public class FrameReplaceComp {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello swing");
    final JLabel label = new JLabel("Label 1");
    frame.add(label);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 100);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    final JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Label 2");
    frame.remove(label);
    frame.add(label1);
    frame.setSize(300,101);

  }
}
```